# How to remove comma from crystal report string and from integer field

Tags: crystal-reports

How can I remove the comma (,) from crystal report fields?

I have a field name "year" which is having a value of `2012`, but when I show that value in crystal report it includes a comma, becoming `2,012`.

How can I show only `2012`?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In the crystal report designer view:

Right mouse click on that field, and select `Format object`. Select `Custom Style` in the Style list, and click `Customize`. Untick `Thousands Separator`, and any other unwanted formatting.

Failing that, you could try selecting the field and deleting the "," value from the  property `ThousandSeperator` in your properties window.

[image]

Comment: What environment are you using this in? Visual Studio?

Comment: i m using asp.net framework 2010 and using crystal report 2008

Comment: apparently, this formula should work: 

CStr(YourField, 0, '')

See [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/179555/Avoiding-thousand-separator-in-Crystal-Report-Fiel) for more detail.

Comment: Im using VS2008 with Crystal Reports basic to be honest, so not sure in what ways your version differs from mine, but in the report designer view... I can literally right mouse click on any field in the report and select "format object".

Comment: i m also very aware for that format object options but even i don't know that this time my system crystal report viewer is not showing that property window etc....

Answer (score 19):

try this
for formula

```
ToText( ToNumber({variable1}), "#" )
```

Comment: best answer ever.

Comment: totext({var},0,"")

Answer (score 10):

Try below code,

```
Replace (ToText ({Tablename.Year_Field}, 0),"," ,"" )
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm just guessing but I believe you have embedded your field name into another object such as a text field.

If this is the case, double click your text box in the design view, then select your text field you are having issues with.  Right click and select "Text Formatting", under the Font tab click the 'Format Formula Editor' button (the one with the X-2) to the right of the Font drop down menu.  Now all you have to do is close the formula editor, then cancel the Text Format window.  NOW when you right click on your year field again you will have a new option to Format the field which was previously grayed out.

Alternatively, you can remove your year field from any other object it is nested in.  This will give you access to all formatting options.

Answer (score 1):

NumberVar cRed;
ToText (cRed,"#")

OR

ToText({some numeric field value},"#")

The "#" has to be enclosed in parenthesis, single or double.