# Datetime in Crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports, formula

How do I set only the date in Crystal report? Also how do I remove the comma from numbers in the ID column?

I created a formula for `fromdate` and `todate` like this. How do I set only the date in `fromdate` and `todate` and remove the comma from numbers in the ID column?

[image: formula]

Here is how I fetch the ID column from the database:

[image]

Comment: If someone give an answer. just give him a points for there efforts.not just reading and get the answer like nothing happens.

Comment: @reds sorry for that i can not read your last comments on this topic Pass HTML id in another web form ... and i try your solution but this show errors and also i comment on your question ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

To convert date use

```
CDate(datetime field);
```

To remove `,` use

```
    ToText(ID,'#') //If this one throws error or 
ToText(ID,0,"")
```

Comment: When i create formula for id ToText({DataTable1.ID},'#') this show error on '#'

Comment: and for datetime i can use fields i display datetime value from page to crystal report

Answer (score 0):

In your date formula use:

```
date({table.field})
```

To remove the comma see:

[How to remove comma from crystal report string and from integer field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13472161/how-to-remove-comma-from-crystal-report-string-and-from-integer-field)

Comment: i can not use field for date time . there is datepicker on page so i display that value in report ...

Answer (score 0):

**To Remove ','**

Write click on Id and Select Format Objects 
and select appropriate option you want to use.
be Sure Id is not string or other than numeric data type.